# Why can't I change my PS1 in my bash login shell?

Tags: bash, shell, configuration, environment-variables

When I ssh into this one remote system I'm unable to modify `PS1`. However, while I'm ssh'd in, if I start a non-login Bash, then I'm able to modify `PS1`. Here's my console output:

```
dev ~ ❯ bash --login
dev ~ ❯ echo $PS1
dev \W ❯
dev ~ ❯ PS1="foobar: "
dev ~ ❯ echo $PS1
dev \W ❯
dev ~ ❯ bash
dev ~ ❯ PS1="foobar: "
foobar: echo $PS1
foobar:
foobar:
```

Here's the same output but with `echo` statements at the beginning and end of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`, and `~/.bashrc`:

```
dev ~ ❯ bash --login
bash_profile
bash_login
profile
bashrc
bashrc end
profile end
bash_login end
bash_profile end
dev ~ ❯ echo $PS1
dev \W ❯
dev ~ ❯ PS1="foobar: "
dev ~ ❯ echo $PS1
dev \W ❯
dev ~ ❯ bash
bashrc
bashrc end
dev ~ ❯ PS1="foobar: "
foobar: echo $PS1
foobar:
foobar:
```

On the system, the default `PS1` appears to be getting set inside of `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
PS1='${ENV:-${ENVIRONMENT:-$(basename HOSTNAME)}} \W ❯ '
```

That file seems to be getting sourced from `/etc/profile`.

```
# If PS1 is not set, load bashrc || zshenv or set the prompt
# shellcheck disable=SC1091
if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
  if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "${BASH}" != '/bin/sh' ]; then
    [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ] && . /etc/bash.bashrc
  # elif [ "${ZSH-}" ] && [ "${ZSH}" != '/bin/sh' ]; then
  #   [ -f /etc/zshenv ] && . /etc/zshenv
  else
    # lightning symbol \342\232\241
    "${IS_ROOT}" && PS1='\[\342\232\241\] ' || PS1='❯ '
  fi
fi
```

Note: In the end I'd like to be able to set `PS1` inside of `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Welcome on U&L! What operating system are you using? Relatively wild guess: `PROMPT_COMMAND` is set, but not exported, in one of Bash's profile files (not in `.bashrc` nor in `/etc/bash.bashrc`), and its value sets `PS1`. Your non-login shell thus has no `PROMPT_COMMAND` (or its value at that point doesn't set `PS1`), stopping overriding the value you manually set.

Comment: @fra-san I didn't notice your comment before I wrote an answer saying the same thing.  Please consider adding an answer, and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @fra-san Thanks for the warm welcome! echo-ing out $PROMPT_COMMAND showed that it was indeed set. Unsetting it allowed me to change PS1.

Comment: @AndyDalton No worries, you did the right thing anyway. I'm a fan of the "comments are released to the public domain" policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fra-san mentioned this in a comment above before I added this answer -- credit goes to him.

It's possible that something in `${PROMPT_COMMAND}` is setting the prompt.  I can reproduce your issue with:

```bsh
function set_ps1() {
    PS1="hi> "
}

$ PROMPT_COMMAND="set_ps1"
hi> PS1="hello "
hi>
```

In this case, when I try to set PS1 to `"hello"`, it changes it, runs `PROMPT_COMMAND`.  That function changes `PS1` back before displaying the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

in `/home/[username]/.bashrc` I added:

```
unset PROMPT_COMMAND
PS1="[\h:\w] "
```

this unsets the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable and then allows me to set the `PS1`.